# Overwriting a file leaves the file blank, doesn't add new data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a set of automated testing scripts.  When trying to write some stats out to a file at a fully specified path, any attempts to overwrite the old version of the file just leave the file empty.  There are a lot of files involved and a series of imports between modules, so forgive me if my attempts to condense remove necessary information.

For context, here is the file structure of my application:

```
main.py (imports all sub#.py classes)
template.py
...
dir1
   --- sub1.py (imports, extends class from template.py)
   --- breakpoint_screenshots
          --- url.txt (output file)
   --- hover_screenshots
          --- url.txt
dir2
   --- sub2.py
   --- breakpoint_screenshots
          --- url.txt
   --- subdir2
          --- url.txt
dir3
   --- sub3.py
   --- breakpoint_screenshots
          --- url.txt
   --- hover_screenshots
          --- url.txt
```

The faulty method is defined in template.py's class and called in sub#.py's inheriting class.  Here's sample code from it:

```
 # test starter code
  def start_test(self, browser, type, script_directory):
    if type == "hover":
      self.__empty_dir__(browser, script_directory + "/hover_screenshots/")
      location = script_directory + "\\hover_screenshots\\url.txt"
      try:
        os.remove(location)
      except:
        pass
      try:
        the_url_file = open(location, "w")
        the_url_file.writelines([str(self.page)])
        the_url_file.close()
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    elif type == "breakpoint":
      self.__empty_dir__(browser, script_directory + "/breakpoint_screenshots/")
      location = script_directory + "\\breakpoint_screenshots\\url.txt"
      try:
        os.remove(location)
      except:
        pass
      try:
        the_url_file = open(location, "w")
        the_url_file.writelines([str(self.page)])
        the_url_file.close()
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
      raise Exception("Incorrect test type " + str(type) + " for test starter.")
```

At some point when execution returns to main.py, the contents of the file are lost and it is left blank.  During the execution of this particular method within a sub#.py module, the file is readable and contains the expected content that was just written.

The path provided to the `open` statement is valid and is the desired path.  I originally used a `with` block, and I've made sure to always close the file as soon as I'm done with it.  I also seemed to notice that it wrote out the correct content as long as it was writing a new file and not overwriting, though I didn't test that too thoroughly.  Despite the file being left blank after the overwrite, the OS says that it was edited at the expected time, so it is successfully accessing and attempting to modify the file.

My observations seem to indicate that the file contents are lost after execution returns to main.py.  They are accessible (via `read` or `readlines`) within the sub#.py, but by the end of of main.py's execution, the files are blank.  Each sub#.py is accessed one at a time in a loop within main.py to run the same function in each of them, so I'm wondering if there is some weird functionality that I don't understand about handling multiple files within a single loop.  I'd appreciate any guidance any of you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I had another function in main.py that was using mode `w+` to read from these files and should have been using mode `r` instead.  So the lesson to learn is to avoid using `w+` when trying to just read a file.  While `w+` allows reading, I think it was still overwriting the file before it tried to read it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists and you use "w", it will clear its contents and then write the new data. If you want to append data to an existing file without overwriting its contents, you should use the "a" (append) mode instead.

The corrected code would look like:
`the_url_file = open(location, "a")`

Comment: I'm looking to overwrite, not append.  The problem is that it does technically overwrite the file (proven by the most recent update date/time) but leaves it blank once the script is finished rather than inserting the new data.